# strange results with IDA (some function different Pseudo Code)

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly

After show the pseudo code in IDA I see different results:

[image]

[image]

The function 4436C0 show different pseudo code.

For example:

```
result = sub_4376C0("vvcbb3.wav",v8,0);
```

and

```
result = sub_4376C0((int)"vvcbb3.wav",v8,0);
```

Have you never seen a similar situation?

It is a IDA bug ?

Comment: Hi! A couple of points you need to mention to make this question better
1. Post code as text instead of pictures
2. Please add more details on what's the exact "result" that you were expecting and what's happening. Also add more context to the problem if you can.

Comment: If you open a function in decompile view in IDA, IDA will try to guess the type of the function args based heuristics such as the operations that are performed over them. You might have decompiled `sub_4376C0` after you took the first screenshot and then return back to `sub_4436C0`

Comment: Thank you !!!I have hook correct the function sub_4376C0 and work fine. but the first parameter is a integer and I need get the real string value passed "vvcbb3.wav" inside this function:

result = sub_4376C0((int)"vvcbb3.wav",v8,0); 

sub_4376C0(int a1, int a2, int a3)

Do you known how I can get the string passed of the first parameter ?

Comment: You can modify the function definition at any time in IDA. by doing so you can change the type of every parameter or even add/remove parameters that have been detected incorrectly (assuming you know the exact function definition).

Comment: thank you Robert, if possible I like to avoid to update the game exe. For your opinion is possible get the string value by modify my hook.dll c++ source code ?

Comment: I would add that you shouldn't base only at the decompilation output, it may be misleading or even wrong, you should pay more attention to the assembly instructions

Comment: thank you morsisko and Robert, I confirm that decompilation output seem wrong. I have used string paramter and work.